# Lua - Is it possible to check if 2 functions are equal?

Tags: function, lua, byte, equals

Is it either possible to get the size of a function in bytes to see if it matches another function similar to C++ sizeof operator, or evaluate two functions some other way to see if they are both equal without actually knowing what the function/s are? Example:

```
local function equals(func1, func2)
   -- check them and return true if equal
end
```

If this is not possible just say and that will satisfy my answer!
Thank you!

EDIT: The body of one function is what I need to check to see if it is the same as another function's body. The reference in memory will be different so I cannot use "==" but the function's reference name can be different.

Comment: Are `function f(x) return x+1 end` and `function g(x) return x+1 end` equal?

Comment: Yes and that would work. The key reference f and g doesn't actually matter. I just was looking for a way to check if the body is equal.

Comment: Then it's impossible unless you have the source. A function might be loaded from i.e. bytecode.

Comment: `sizeof` operator can't be used to compare if functions are equal in C++.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Yu Hao I know sizeof doesn't work like that in C++ which is why I put "similar" as it returns the bytes in memory that a variable uses which is what I wish lua could do for functions or any variable for that matter

Comment: @lhf I wanted to create a function that would compare two tables to see if they were equal but functions proved to be much harder to deal with. The function basically should only add a new element to a metatable if the element was not already found in the 2nd table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `==` for functions only checks if they reference to the same function, which is not what you expected.

This task is rather difficult, if not impossible at all. For really simple cases, here's an idea:

```
function f(x) return x + 1 end
local g = function(y) return y + 1 end
```

`f` and `g` are two function that are equal by your definition. Assuming the file is `t.lua`, run:

```
luac -l t.lua
```

The output is:

```
main <t.lua:0,0> (4 instructions at 00000000003081c0)
0+ params, 2 slots, 1 upvalue, 1 local, 1 constant, 2 functions
        1       [1]     CLOSURE         0 0     ; 0000000000308330
        2       [1]     SETTABUP        0 -1 0  ; _ENV "f"
        3       [2]     CLOSURE         0 1     ; 0000000000308dc0
        4       [2]     RETURN          0 1

function <t.lua:1,1> (3 instructions at 0000000000308330)
1 param, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 1 local, 1 constant, 0 functions
        1       [1]     ADD             1 0 -1  ; - 1
        2       [1]     RETURN          1 2
        3       [1]     RETURN          0 1

function <t.lua:2,2> (3 instructions at 0000000000308dc0)
1 param, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 1 local, 1 constant, 0 functions
        1       [2]     ADD             1 0 -1  ; - 1
        2       [2]     RETURN          1 2
        3       [2]     RETURN          0 1
```

As you can see, the two functions have the same instructions in the virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think that's as close as I will get. Shame there's no easier way but I'll have to make do :)

Comment: If access to the bytecode gets you closer to a solution, there is [lbci](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbci), a bytecode inspector library (for Lua 5.1 and 5.2, also installable via LuaRocks) written by @lhf, which could give you the same information as `luac -l` above.

Answer (score 6):

Will comparing the bytecode do?

```
local function equals(func1, func2)
    return string.dump(func1) == string.dump(func2)
end
```

Surely, there would be some cases were the above would fail. For instance:

```
local function f1 (...)
    local a = print
    a(...)
end

local function f2 (...)
    print(...)
end


local function equals (f1, f2)
    return string.dump(f1) == string.dump(f2)
end

print(equals(f1,f2))   --> false
```

Both functions do the same thing, but they generate different bytecode. Maybe if you state what you're trying to achive, a better solution than function comparison can be provided.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I have to check whether two tables are identical so that only new entries to one table are added if they do not appear in another table and I can easily compare whether a value is in another table already but functions are much trickier as == only compares memory addresses.

Comment: `string.dump` would fail even for this: `function a() end`
`function b()  end` `print(string.dump(a) == string.dump(b))` Outputs `false`.

Comment: You should strip debug info from dumps before comparing: `string.dump(f1, true) == string.dump(f2, true)`.  It works perfectly on LuaJIT (but for some reason doesnot work on Lua 5.3).

Comment: Didn't know about the "strip" debug flag (introduced in Lua 5.3). Thanks. It surprised me that Yu Hao's example failed.